# How can I insert database value in LARAVEL herf route name

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6, location-href, laravel-route

How can I insert database value in Laravel href route name ?
Is this possible?

```
<a href="{{route('user.{{$adminbank->link}}')}}">{{$adminbank->bank_name}}</a>
```

Comment: Not clear your problem. Please explain details

Comment: Yes possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your route name is something like `user.show` and `$adminbank->link` is "show":

```
<a href="{{route('user.' . $adminbank->link)}}">{{$adminbank->bank_name}}</a>
```

(Don't use `{{ }}` inside `{{ }}`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{route("user.{$adminbank->link}")}}">{{$adminbank->bank_name}}</a>
```